# Serilog stops logging events

Tags: serilog

I have created a Serilog sink that talks to a web service which persists log messages to a database. It works most of the time. Even in cases where there is an exception calling the web service it will log to the Selflog file. However, However, periodically it simply stops logging either to our custom web service or to the self log file and after it stops logging it never begins logging anywhere else. This is being executed in a windows service and I have to stop and restart the windows service before it begins logging again. A typical exception that i might get from the web service call is: "Task was cancelled". This would be caused because the webservice does not respond within the configured timeout period. As I said normally it will properly write the events to the selflog file. Only periodically will it just stop logging everywhere. I should also say that the volume of logs being generated is very high.

This is a dnx project and here is a portion of the project.json file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.2",
    "Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching": "2.0.0",
    "Serilog": "2.0.0-beta-465",
    "Serilog.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final-10092",
    "JA.AppCentral.Logging.Contracts": "0.1.0-alpha1-*",
    "FluentAssertions": "4.2.2",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client": "4.0.30506"
  }
```

I have included relevant portions of the sink class. It inherits from periodic batching sink.

The code used to configure the Selflog follows:

```
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(selfLogFilePath, fileMode, FileAccess.Write);
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
    Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Out = TextWriter.Synchronized(sw);
```

Here is the sink code:`enter code here`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Serilog;
using System.Net.Http;
using Serilog.Core;
using Serilog.Events;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.IO;
using Serilog.Formatting.Json;
using Serilog.Debugging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using JA.AppCentral.Logging.Contracts;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace JA.AppCentral.Logging

{

    public class AppCentralSink: Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching.PeriodicBatchingSink
    {
        readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        LoggingLevelSwitch _levelControlSwitch;
        const string BulkAddUri = "api/appLogging/bulkAdd";
        private Uri _baseUri;
        private string _baseUriPath;
        readonly long? _eventBodyLimitBytes = 1000000;
        static readonly TimeSpan RequiredLevelCheckInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        private TimeSpan _timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        private bool _saveMessageTemplate;
        private int eventsCount;
        private LoggingRepositoryServiceResponse _logServiceResponse;
        private int _totalInsertedRecords;
        public event EventHandler<ResponseEventArgs> ResponseReceived = delegate { };

        DateTime _nextRequiredLevelCheckUtc = DateTime.Now.Add(RequiredLevelCheckInterval);

        private int osId;
        private string server;
        private string username;
        private int threadId;
        private string appcode;


        /// <summary>
        /// Overloaded constructor, to pass AppSettings via IConfiguration , instead of separate parameters
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="config"></param>
        public AppCentralSink(IConfiguration config)
                : base(Convert.ToInt32(GetConfigParams(config)["BatchSizeLimit"]), 
                      TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(GetConfigParams(config)["BatchEmitIntervalSeconds"])))
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> appSettingDict = GetConfigParams(config);
            long tempLongVal;
            long? eventBodyLimitBytes = long.TryParse(appSettingDict["EventBodyMaxSizeBytes"], out tempLongVal) ? tempLongVal : (long?)null;
            if (eventBodyLimitBytes != null)
                _eventBodyLimitBytes = eventBodyLimitBytes;

            bool saveMessageTemplate = Convert.ToBoolean(appSettingDict["LogMessageTemplate"]);
            if (saveMessageTemplate != false)
                _saveMessageTemplate = saveMessageTemplate;

            string serverUrl = appSettingDict["Url"];
            //baseUri = "http://localhost:49774/"; 

            if (!serverUrl.EndsWith("/"))
                serverUrl += "/";
            _baseUriPath = serverUrl;
            _baseUri = new Uri(serverUrl);

            TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(appSettingDict["WebRequestTimeoutSeconds"]));
            if (timeout != default(TimeSpan))
                _timeout = timeout;

            //Default Authentication via http client handler
            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                PreAuthenticate = true,
                UseDefaultCredentials = true
            };

            _httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
            _httpClient.BaseAddress = _baseUri;
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            _httpClient.Timeout = _timeout;

            //Init Context properties
            OsId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
            Server = Environment.MachineName;
            Username = Environment.UserName;
            ThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            Appcode = config["JA:AppCatalog:AppCode"];

        }


        private static Dictionary<string,string> GetConfigParams(IConfiguration config)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> appSettings = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            var SerilogSection = config.GetSection("AppCentralLogging");
            appSettings.Add("Url", SerilogSection["Url"]);
            appSettings.Add("BatchSizeLimit", SerilogSection["BatchSizeLimit"]);
            appSettings.Add("BatchEmitIntervalSeconds", SerilogSection["BatchEmitIntervalSeconds"]);
            appSettings.Add("EventBodyMaxSizeBytes", SerilogSection["EventBodyMaxSizeBytes"]);
            appSettings.Add("LogMessageTemplate", SerilogSection["LogMessageTemplate"]);
            appSettings.Add("WebRequestTimeoutSeconds", SerilogSection["WebRequestTimeoutSeconds"]);

            appSettings.Add("SelfLogFileLocationAndPrefix", config["Serilog:SelfLogFileLocationAndPrefix"]);

            return appSettings;
        }

        // The sink must emit at least one event on startup, and the server be
        // configured to set a specific level, before background level checks will be performed.
        protected override void OnEmptyBatch()
        {
            if (_levelControlSwitch != null &&
                _nextRequiredLevelCheckUtc < DateTime.Now)
            {
                EmitBatch(Enumerable.Empty<LogEvent>());
            }
        }


        protected override async Task EmitBatchAsync(IEnumerable<LogEvent> events)
        {
            _nextRequiredLevelCheckUtc = DateTime.Now.Add(RequiredLevelCheckInterval);

            var formatter = new JsonFormatter();
            List<LogEntry> logEntriesList = new List<LogEntry>();
            try
            {
                foreach (var logEvent in events)
                {
                    EventsCount++;
                    LogEntry jaLogEvent = ConvertToLogEntry(logEvent);

                    if (_eventBodyLimitBytes.HasValue)
                    {
                        var scratch = new StringWriter();
                        formatter.Format(logEvent, scratch);
                        var buffered = scratch.ToString();

                        if (Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(buffered) > _eventBodyLimitBytes.Value)
                        {
                            SelfLog.WriteLine("Event JSON representation exceeds the byte size limit of {0} set for this sink and will be dropped; data: {1}", _eventBodyLimitBytes, buffered);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            logEntriesList.Add(jaLogEvent);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        logEntriesList.Add(jaLogEvent);
                    }
                }

                var result = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(BulkAddUri, logEntriesList);


                if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var error = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        var responseExcep = new Exception(error);
                        throw responseExcep;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        SelfLog.WriteLine("FailedEvents: " + GetEventsAsString(events));
                        throw new Exception("Error calling Logging Web Service: status code: " + result.StatusCode +
                                   " reason: " + result.ReasonPhrase + " excep: " + e.ToString());
                    }
                }
                _logServiceResponse = await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<LoggingRepositoryServiceResponse>();
                if (_logServiceResponse.ResponseException != null)
                {
                    SelfLog.WriteLine("FailedEvents: " + GetEventsAsString(events));
                    SelfLog.WriteLine(_logServiceResponse.ResponseMessage);
                    throw new Exception("Error calling Logging Web Service: " +
                                    _logServiceResponse.ResponseMessage);
                }
                _totalInsertedRecords = _totalInsertedRecords + _logServiceResponse.NumRecordsInserted;
                ResponseReceived(this, new ResponseEventArgs(result));

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                    SelfLog.WriteLine("Error processing log batch, excep: " + e.ToString());
                    SelfLogEvents(events);
                    throw;
            }
        }


        private void SelfLogEvents(IEnumerable<LogEvent> events)
        {
            SelfLog.WriteLine("Failed to write following log events:");
            foreach (var e in events)
            {
                SelfLog.WriteLine($"  Event: " + e.RenderMessage());
            }
        }

        private string GetEventsAsString(IEnumerable<LogEvent> events)
        {
            string eventsResult = string.Empty;
            foreach(LogEvent le in events)
            {
                eventsResult += "[" + le.RenderMessage() + "]";
            }

            return eventsResult;
        }

        private LogEntry ConvertToLogEntry(LogEvent logEvent)
        {
            string propertiesString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logEvent.Properties);
            string messageTemplate = _saveMessageTemplate == true ? logEvent.MessageTemplate.Text : string.Empty;

            //Append Exception to the message if it's not null
            string logEventMessage = logEvent.RenderMessage();
            if (logEvent.Exception != null)
            {
                logEventMessage = logEventMessage + " Exception: " + logEvent.Exception.ToString();
            }

            LogEntry logEntry = new LogEntry("AppCode", "Action", logEvent.Level.ToString(), messageTemplate,
                                                        logEventMessage, propertiesString,
                                                        logEvent.Timestamp);
            //Append additional properties
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Appcode))
            {
                logEntry.AppCode = logEvent.Properties.Keys.Contains("appcode") ? logEvent.Properties["appcode"].ToString().Replace("\"", "") : string.Empty;                
                logEntry.OsPId = logEvent.Properties.Keys.Contains("os_pid") ? logEvent.Properties["os_pid"].ToString().Replace("\"", "") : string.Empty;
                logEntry.ThreadId = logEvent.Properties.Keys.Contains("thread_id") ? logEvent.Properties["thread_id"].ToString().Replace("\"", "") : string.Empty;
                logEntry.Server = logEvent.Properties.Keys.Contains("server") ? logEvent.Properties["server"].ToString().Replace("\"", "") : string.Empty;
                logEntry.Username = logEvent.Properties.Keys.Contains("username") ? logEvent.Properties["username"].ToString().Replace("\"", "") : string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                logEntry.AppCode = Appcode;
                logEntry.OsPId = OsId.ToString();
                logEntry.ThreadId = ThreadId.ToString();
                logEntry.Server = Server;
                logEntry.Username = Username;

            }

            logEntry.SessionId = logEvent.Properties.Keys.Contains("session_id") ? logEvent.Properties["session_id"].ToString().Replace("\"", "") : string.Empty;
            logEntry.Action = logEvent.Properties.Keys.Contains("action") ? logEvent.Properties["action"].ToString().Replace("\"", "") : string.Empty;

            //Append SourceContext
            //Append SourceContext
            LogEventPropertyValue propertyValue;
            if (logEvent.Properties.TryGetValue("SourceContext", out propertyValue))
            {
                logEntry.SourceContext = propertyValue.ToString().Trim(new[] { '"' });
            }


            return logEntry;
        }


        public int EventsCount
        {
            get
            {
                return eventsCount;
            }

            set
            {
                eventsCount = value;
            }
        }

        public LoggingRepositoryServiceResponse LogServiceResponse
        {
            get
            {
                return _logServiceResponse;
            }

            set
            {
                _logServiceResponse = value;
            }
        }

        public int TotalInsertedRecords
        {
            get
            {
                return _totalInsertedRecords;
            }

            set
            {
                _totalInsertedRecords = value;
            }
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);

            if (disposing)
                _httpClient.Dispose();
        }

        public HttpClient HttpClient
        {
            get { return _httpClient; }
        }

    }

    public class ResponseEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public ResponseEventArgs(HttpResponseMessage response)
        {
            Response = response;
        }

        public HttpResponseMessage Response { get; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `PeriodicBatchingSink` will back-off exponentially if an error is thrown from `EmitBatchAsync()` - the duration depends on the batch period, so it may pause for quite a while.

Comment: Also, any reason not to upgrade Serilog and Serilog.Extensions.Logging to RTM versions?

Comment: thanks for your answer. I looked at the periodicbatchsink code and saw how it backs off upon throwing errors. I also saw that if using a bounded queue and the queue is full it throws the error away. I should think that it should selflog this.